# How to delete all entries in Core Data on my phone from Xcode?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I would like to delete all entries in my core data on my iphone some time to time as I run my app.

I just want to check my saving workflow is working but I don't want to do it programatically.

I mean, is there a command/button that from Xcode, sends a message to reset the Core Data entries for the app ran from xcode?

Thanks

Comment: You can always delete the .sqlite file from within your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any functionality to do that directly from Xcode.

This is what I do:

If you are in the simulator, you can go and look for the SQLite file and open it, then remove the entries that you want. (Remenber that your app must be close if not you will get core data errors due the fact that the managed object context will cache what you removed).

In a device, the faster way to reset a db is directly removing the file. 
If your core data code handle the creation of the persistent store if it can't find the file at start. You can get into your phone using any app that you like (ie. imazing.com) and remove the sql file and then start again from scratch.
Hope it helps.

I have this code to clean entities, keeping in mind memory pressure loading only the ObjectId and some other tweaks. Core data sucks when you wants to remove to many objects. A cascade rule for deletions using a 1 to n relationship it's a good solution too.

```
- (BOOL) resetEntity:(NSString*)entityName
       withPredicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate
inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
            andError:(NSError **)error
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    [fetchRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; //only fetch the managedObjectID to optimize.
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSManagedObjectIDResultType;
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20]; //reduce memory usage
    
    if (predicate)
    {
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    }
    
    NSError * fetchError = nil;
    NSArray * objects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];
    
    if (fetchError)
    {
        DDLogError(@"ERROR: Core Data Reset %@ : %@", entityName, fetchError);
        *error = fetchError;
        return NO;
    }
    
    for (NSManagedObjectID * objectID in objects)
    {
        [context deleteObject:[context objectWithID:objectID]];
    }
    
    NSError *saveError = nil;
    [context save:&saveError];
    if (saveError) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Core Data Reset %@ : %@", entityName, fetchError);
        *error = saveError;
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but on the device, is there any advantage doing you method than just deleting the app from the phone?

Comment: If you only have the db, no advantages at all. But if you have more files that you don't want to remove like images, files, etc, it could be useful.

Comment: hmm ok. Then I guess I might had a temp button to do it programmatically as your solution might be a little long if I have to do this all the time. But thanks it's good to know we can to it that way as well.

Comment: Just updated my answer, it sucks becouse I'm using my phone  sorry. But there are some good ideas to keep in mind if you want to do it manually.